# Symfony: Prod environment on webserver produces blank page

Tags: symfony

my Symfony 3 app works flawless on my local webserver. Since it´s been installed on the remote web server it produces a blank page, even the routing doesn't work. After editing *web/app.php* `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);` and set it to *true*, the application works as expected and does not display any errors.
Why does the application behave different on the local and the remote webserver. Did I miss to configure something on the remote server?
Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: display the php error on the webserver so you can see what is the error

Comment: Did you clear and the warmup the cache with `env=prod`?

Comment: Yes, I cleared the cache for the prod environment a million times.

Comment: display_errors: "Interface 'ProxyManager\Proxy\VirtualProxyInterface' not found". I get this error only, when AppKernel['prod'] is set to 'false'. By changing it to 'true' the error doesn't occure and the page is displayed as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I have a solution to solve the problem: after the composer update I have to clear the cache of the prod environment manually by executing `rm -fr var/cache/prod/*`. For whatever reason does the command `php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod` quit working immediately after the composer update without throwing any error messages. After removing the cache files manually both the application and the `cache:clear` command work as expected without modifying *web/app.php*.

Comment: Same issue here, and your solution is the one that helped. Works like a charm now ! Thx for your time.

Answer (score 1):

1.check permission   to cache  and  log   dirs ( need to be 777 )

2.check (paste here) error  in  logs/prod.log

Comment: _var/cache_ and _var/logs_ were set to 755. Though I think, those permission are ok, I set it to 777 as you suggested. Although there are no errors in _logs/prod.log_ after new page requests.

Comment: ok  , so  it's  not php exeption  . you need to access to apache/nginx  log and see errors there

Comment: no errors in the server logs.
I wonder why there´s no problem by setting AppKernel['prod'] to 'true'?

Comment: Beware of this response, permissions need to be **775, not 777** (security issues otherwise)

Answer (score 0):

Since I couldn´t find out what´s the real cause of this problem I´ve made a fresh install of my application and updated Symfony and all dependencies with composer. 
Although I did the same with the old installation, it does the trick this time. My guess is, something went wrong with the composer update before.
Thanks again for your help! If someone has a similar problem I would appreciate if you could post how you solved the problem (or why AppKernel['prod'] = 'true' did work).

Answer (score 0):

I have plausible explanation, what might have been the problem.

I have encountered this problem earlier this year with Symfony3, while developing on Windows but deploying manually (copying project's files) to shared server with Linux.

As you say - blank page in `prod` environment.

- To add to the mystery `log` files did not show any problems
- So i enabled `dev` environment to check what is wrong
- application worked as intended if i added `app_dev.php` in the `URL`

I overviewed all the files, more than once, but `copy` was done correctly.

### The answer

After some time I "came across" the file: `bootstrap.php.cache` in `var` directory. It "felt suspicious".

As I had exhausted my options `i just deleted it` to test the result.

That solved it in my case.
Site was running again.
No more blank page!

I guess mixed development environment has its toll.

Comment: In my case this didn't help. I had to clear the entire cache manually after the composer update.

Comment: I tried copying without cache folder, so server had to generate them on first user visit. Yet it did not result in working application. Though deleting `bootstrap.php.cache` did it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your production server is set up to not show any errors, so in order to see them you need to place this at the top of your index.php file:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```